# Ionic 2 : Firebase Cloud Messaging and Google services errors

Tags: firebase, ionic2, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-authentication

I have tried searching at a ton of places to get FCM working. I am using Google Authentication API and have just installed FCM to use Push Notifications. I would like to use both of them. When i do build I get these errors. 
    * What went wrong:
            A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.

> Failed to apply plugin [class 'com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin']

```
        BUILD FAILED

        Total time: 3.002 secs
        > For input string: "+"
```

This is my project.properties file

```
target=android-25
android.library.reference.1=CordovaLib
cordova.system.library.1=com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+
cordova.system.library.2=com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:+
cordova.system.library.3=com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:+
cordova.system.library.4=com.android.support:support-v13:25.1.0
cordova.system.library.5=me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.17@aar
cordova.system.library.6=com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.1
cordova.gradle.include.1=phonegap-plugin-push/starter-push.gradle
```

Couple of things I tried after reading lot of posts:
1. I removed and added android platform then did the build.
2. I tried changing the versions of below libraries to numerous values, but it does not help.

```
cordova.system.library.2=com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:+
cordova.system.library.3=com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:+
```

If try changing the version from + to 3.0.0 or 9.8.0 or any version I get this error for firebase

```
 * What went wrong:
        A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
        > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':_debugApkCopy'.
        > Could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.1.
        Required by:
        project :
```

Note: Changing the same inside the build.gradle file dosen't help as it gets overridden when we do a build.

this is my package.json.

```
{
    "name": "test",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "author": "Ionic Framework",
    "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
        "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
        "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint",
        "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
        "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve",
        "start": "node ./bin/www"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@angular/common": "4.1.2",
        "@angular/compiler": "4.1.2",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.1.2",
        "@angular/core": "4.1.2",
        "@angular/forms": "4.1.2",
        "@angular/http": "4.1.2",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "4.1.2",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.1.2",
        "@ionic-native/core": "3.10.2",
        "@ionic-native/facebook": "^3.10.2",
        "@ionic-native/google-plus": "^3.12.1",
        "@ionic-native/native-storage": "^3.10.3",
        "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "3.10.2",
        "@ionic-native/status-bar": "3.10.2",
        "@ionic/storage": "2.0.1",
        "body-parser": "^1.17.2",
        "cordova-android": "^6.2.3",
        "cordova-plugin-console": "^1.0.5",
        "cordova-plugin-device": "^1.1.4",
        "cordova-plugin-facebook4": "^1.9.0",
        "cordova-plugin-googleplus": "^5.1.1",
        "cordova-plugin-nativestorage": "^2.2.2",
        "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^4.0.3",
        "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.2.2",
        "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.1",
        "express": "^4.15.3",
        "ionic-angular": "3.3.0",
        "ionic-native": "^2.5.1",
        "ionic-plugin-keyboard": "^2.2.1",
        "ionicons": "3.0.0",
        "mongoose": "^4.11.4",
        "morgan": "^1.8.2",
        "phonegap-plugin-push": "^2.0.0",
        "rxjs": "5.1.1",
        "serve-favicon": "^2.4.3",
        "socket.io": "^2.0.3",
        "socket.io-client": "^2.0.3",
        "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
        "zone.js": "0.8.11"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@ionic/app-scripts": "1.3.7",
        "@ionic/cli-plugin-cordova": "1.6.2",
        "@ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular": "1.4.1",
        "ionic": "3.7.0",
        "typescript": "2.3.3"
    },
    "description": "An Ionic project",
    "cordova": {
        "plugins": {
            "cordova-plugin-console": {},
            "cordova-plugin-device": {},
            "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
            "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
            "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
            "ionic-plugin-keyboard": {},
            "cordova-plugin-facebook4": {
                "APP_ID": "xxxxxxx2",
                "APP_NAME": "test"
            },
            "cordova-plugin-googleplus": {
                "REVERSED_CLIENT_ID": "4xxxxxxxx6-7dsgct91usuntkmomme1n8rq5i7oipq8.apps.googleusercontent.com"
            },
            "phonegap-plugin-push": {
                "SENDER_ID": "81xxxxx8690"
            }
        },
        "platforms": [
            "android"
        ]
    },
    "main": "index.js",
    "keywords": [
        "server"
    ],
    "license": "ISC"
}
```

Can some one please help me out, suggest a better approach to implement Push notification. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't se FCM plugin in your package.json, but if you've installed it, `phonegap-plugin-push` has some conflicts with the FCM plugin, so you can't have both in your project.

Comment: what would be the work around for that ? i only installed phonegap-plugin-push as per a tutorial https://ampersandacademy.com/tutorials/ionic-framework-version-2/push-notification-in-ionic-2-native-plugin-version-2-3-with-firebase-hosting-service-provider

Comment: There's no workaround for this, you'll need to uninstall push and install FCM https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/fcm/ then follow the documentation from the Ionic page and from the plugin page (link in Ionic page)

Answer (score 0):

Try to install Google Repository

Tools -> SDK Manager -> Google Repository

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qe8iu.png